# How to handle systemctl command using python

Tags: python, nginx, systemctl

I don't understand why the following fails in python (when it works flawlessly in shell) :

```
>>> if subprocess.call('systemctl reload nginx', shell=True):
...   print('ok')
... else:
...   print('NNNNNNNNNNNNNN')
... 
NNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>>> 
root@nginx [~]: systemctl reload nginx
root@nginx [~]: echo $?
0
```

Shell command outputs "0" as for any successful comand but the "equivalent" python code seems to evaluate the command as false, why is that ?

Comment: In shell return code 0 means success, but in Python 0 is False. So you get `if False:`. The correct test should be `if subprocess.call(...) == 0:`

Comment: So what is the preferred way to handle this ? Am i supposed to add a "not" in the condition to get the desired behaviour ? (this seems odd to me)

Comment: Either `retval == 0` or the new API `subprocess.run(..., check=True)` which raises an exception if the call fails.